# Scala Found Unit Expected Future[Result]

Tags: scala, playframework, future

```
def update() = AuthAction.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>

  val list = request.body.asInstanceOf[JsArray].value

  list.foreach( mapping => {
      repository.update()
  }.andThen {
    case Success(value) => repository.update2()
    case Failure(exception) => {
    BadRequest(errorResponse(Json.toJson(""), "updation failed"))
  }
 })

}
```

I have a controller function where I want to wait for a DB repo function ( repository.update2() )to complete and then send a response, but its saying "Found Unit expected Future[Result]"

Comment: Use `map` / `flatMap` rather than `andThen` - Also, you probably also want `Future.traverse` rather than `foreach`

Comment: Also, does `update` returns a `Future`? If not, don't use `AuthAction.async` but just `AuthAction`. If yes, ensure the types are consistent in each code branch: case `Failure` doesn't return a `Future`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success claus is presumably returning Unit where a Future response is required. Try this:

```
.andThen {
    case Success(value) =>
        repository.update2()
        Future.successful(Ok("repository updated"))
    case Failure(exception) =>
        Future.successful(BadRequest(exception.getMessage())))
  }
```